# Error in where clause PL/SQL query selecting from dual

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing the following query,

```
SELECT 'Payment Token,Transaction ID,Create Date' 
  FROM dual 
 UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT 
       pt.mw_payment_token ||','||
       t.mw_transaction_id ||','||
       t.create_date 
  FROM t_mw_payment_token pt, 
       t_mw_transaction t 
 where pt.mw_payment_token =  t.mw_payment_token 
 order by t.mw_transaction_id;
```

Error is:

```
ORA-00904: "T"."MW_TRANSACTION_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 103
```

Why is the column `mw_transaction_id` invalid?

**Edit:**

t_mw_transaction table

```
ENABLECREATE TABLE WFMW.T_MW_TRANSACTION 
(
  MW_PAYMENT_TOKEN VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  CREATE_DATE DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
  MW_TRANSACTION_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  TRANSACTION_TYPE NUMBER(*, 0),
  CONSTRAINT XPK_T_MW_TRANSACTION PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    MW_TRANSACTION_ID 
  )
  ENABLE 
)
```

mw_payment_token table

```
ENABLECREATE TABLE WFMW.T_MW_PAYMENT_TOKEN 
(
  MW_PAYMENT_TOKEN VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, CREATE_DATE DATE 
, MODIFIED_DATE DATE 
, TOKENIZED_PAN VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, CONSTRAINT XPKT_MW_PAYMENT_TOKEN PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    MW_PAYMENT_TOKEN 
  )
  ENABLE 
)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to select `'Paymend Token, Transaction ID, Create Date'` and not `'Payment Token', 'Transaction ID', 'Create Date'` and same for your columns? And how do your tables look like? Is `t_me_transaction` really the column name? Maybe some typo?

Comment: Can you describe t_mw_payment_token pt, t_mw_transaction tables ?

Comment: it looks like you are referencing an alias "ut" (ut.create_date), but I dont see the table it's aliasing ...

Comment: Where did you get `ut` alias in `ut.create_date` when there is no alias like that?

Comment: the ut. is a typo  It's actually t.create_date.

Comment: Most likely your `ORDER BY`-clause as you only have your `pt.mw_payment_token ||','||
       t.mw_transaction_id ||','||
       t.create_date ` column I guess

Comment: It's definitely the order by clause.  But why is that showing as invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
    SELECT 'Payment Token,Transaction ID,Create Date'
    FROM dual 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
             mw_payment_token ||','||
             mw_transaction_id ||','||
             create_date 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
             DISTINCT
             pt.mw_payment_token,
             t.mw_transaction_id,
             t.create_date
             FROM t_mw_payment_token pt, 
             t_mw_transaction t 
             WHERE pt.mw_payment_token =  t.mw_payment_token 
             ORDER BY t.mw_transaction_id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the `ORDER BY`-clause because it's global over the whole query and doesn't recognize `t.mw_transaction_id` in the whole statement.
Same problem as in:

```
select 'a' from dual 
union all
select dummy from dual
order by dummy;
```

You can fix that by giving the columns in both queries the same alias:

```
select 'a' some_col from dual 
union all
select dummy some_col from dual
order by some_col;
```

But I don't think that is what you want to achieve.

**Edit**:
I am not sure what you want to achieve with your query, but maybe this gives you the desired result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       pt.mw_payment_token "Payment Token",
       t.mw_transaction_id "Transaction ID",
       t.create_date "Create Date"
  FROM t_mw_payment_token pt, 
       t_mw_transaction t 
 where pt.mw_payment_token =  t.mw_payment_token 
 order by "Transaction ID";
```

**Edit2**:
If you want your output as CSV, maybe check [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/615034) or [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/615034) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750192/how-to-write-to-files-using-utl-file-in-oracle). Maybe consider asking another question here on SO.
My suggestion would be to use the `UTL_FILE` package iterating over a cursor that is based on my first edit. But I have not tried that so far.

Comment: You're right, I want to order the set by transaction id and output a CSV file - what do you suggest?

Comment: SELECT 'Payment Token,Transaction ID,Create Date', t.mw_transaction_id 
FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT pt.mw_payment_token ||','|| t.mw_transaction_id ||',' || t.create_date
FROM t_mw_payment_token pt, t_mw_transaction t where pt.mw_payment_token = t.mw_payment_token order by t.mw_transaction_id; also gives the same error

Comment: Yeah sure, because again you don't have the `t.mw_transaction_id` column in all subqueries

Comment: Your query works on its own, but not when pulled into select 'xxx' from dual union all

Comment: @KristyWelsh no, why would you want to pull in in there? My second query was a suggestion to maybe get you the result you want. Wasn't sure what you wanted to achieve as you have never said anything about that then

Answer (score 1):

You want an order by clause for only the second part of your statement. Hence:

```
SELECT 'Payment Token,Transaction ID,Create Date'
  FROM dual 
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         pt.mw_payment_token ||','||
         t.mw_transaction_id ||','||
         t.create_date 
    FROM t_mw_payment_token pt, 
         t_mw_transaction t 
   where pt.mw_payment_token =  t.mw_payment_token 
   order by t.mw_transaction_id
);
```

Comment: They are not necessarily sorted after your `SELECT * FROM` as far as I know

Comment: Your answer gives the following error:  ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 12

Comment: Give `alias` to your computed column and then use it in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by an alias - how would that look in the query?

Comment: Sorry, you are all right. I cannot reduce records with DISTINCT and access a record field in ORDER BY at the same time. And yes, there is no guarantee that the result is still sorted correctly. Please Forget about this answer. I wrote another one that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the DISTINCT clause from Thorsten Kettner's answer allowed the query to run.

```
SELECT 'Payment Token,Transaction ID,Create Date'
  FROM dual 
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT 
         pt.mw_payment_token ||','||
         t.mw_transaction_id ||','||
         t.create_date 
    FROM t_mw_payment_token pt, 
         t_mw_transaction t 
   where pt.mw_payment_token =  t.mw_payment_token 
   order by t.mw_transaction_id
);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that you can't be sure that your outcome will be sorted as `SELECT * FROM` may return the values in a random order. It's the same with a table that seems sorted, you can only guarantee an order when using the `ORDER BY`-clause at the end

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was in a hurry when I wrote the other answer. Here is an untested, but hopefully working solution. First collect all records, giving your header a low sort key. Then sort:

```
SELECT the_string
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Payment Token,Transaction ID,Create Date' as the_string, -1 as sort_key
    FROM dual 
   UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT 
           pt.mw_payment_token ||','|| t.mw_transaction_id ||','|| t.create_date as the_string,
           t.mw_transaction_id as sort_key
    FROM t_mw_payment_token pt 
    JOIN t_mw_transaction t ON pt.mw_payment_token =  t.mw_payment_token
)
ORDER BY sort_key
```

Answer (score 0):

order by 1
OR give your column a nice alias in both queries (only 1st matters) and order by it