# Not getting ORA-29285 - File write error (oracle) even the output file is incomplete

Tags: oracle

I've a code in oracle to write data from database to a file.

```
conn := utl_file.fopen('sample_directory','output.csv','W',32000);
for i in (select * from per_data)
loop
utl_file.put_line(conn,i.name||','||i.dept||','||to_char(i.start_date,'dd-mon-  yy')||','||to_char(i.expire_date,'dd-mon-yy')||','||i.loc||','||i.currently||','||i.past||','||i.sub1||','||i.sub2||','||i.sub3||','||i.sub4||','||i.sub5||','||i.sub6||','||i.sub7||','||i.sub8||','||i.sub9||','||i.sub10||','||i.sub11||','||i.sub12||','||i.sub13||','||i.total,TRUE);
end loop;
utl_file.fclose(conn);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   dbms_output.Put_line('SQL Error' || SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
```

Oracle is not throwing `ORA-29285 - File write error` but I can see my output file to be incomplete.

Please Can someone help me out with this issue ?

**Edit:** The same piece of code worked fine before I add two new columns to the output. I mean to say that I had been notified by Oracle that there was `file_write_error` whenever I have an incomplete file.

Comment: The error simply indicates that that it couldnot write the whole data. the output which you are seeing might be incomplete. you need to write a logic when end of the file is reached a new file is opened and data can be wriiten down.

Comment: How is your file incomplete? Are you missing parts of a row or entire rows? How many rows does your table contain?

Comment: What happens if you remove the exception handling?

Comment: @XING My concern is that Oracle is not capturing the error when my file is incomplete. Is there something to change in my code to trace the error ?

Comment: @Aleksej After writing certain number of records to file, the next record is not complete and the rest of the records are not being written to file. I write around 0.1-0.5 million records. And I cannot remove exception handling, as I wanted to be notified when there is some error.

Comment: My doubt is that the problem is in the exception handling, for example if you have not set the serveroutput your message will not be written. Try removing the exception handling, this should hopefully cause the block fail with an Oracle exception

Comment: Why don't you diversify the exception rather than puttin them in a single place. use as below: when utl_file.invalid_path then
raise_application_error(-20001,
'INVALID_PATH: File location or filename was invalid.');
when utl_file.invalid_mode then
raise_application_error(-20002,
'INVALID_MODE: The open_mode parameter in FOPEN was invalid.');
when utl_file.invalid_filehandle then
raise_application_error(-20002,
'INVALID_FILEHANDLE: The file handle was invalid.');

Comment: @Aleksej Sorry for not mentioning that the same code worked fine (server output is on) before I add two new columns to the output. Is it something due to the addition of new columns ?

Comment: Use this examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750192/how-to-write-to-files-using-utl-file-in-oracle

Comment: Maybe the new columns made the output become too big, thus causing the error; check if you set the serveroutput or try to remove the exception handling and see what happens; this could say us the real problem and how to solve

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej. I don't think new columns made the output huge (as they contain single character value). As suggested I'll try removing exception handling and also setting the serveroutput to more size.

Comment: Thanks @XING. I'll try the suggested addition to the code and will come back with the result hopefully to be positive. :)

Comment: All the best..I hope it will certainly solve the issue